# Geometry in calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why can the moons orbit around the earth be expressed as. By the looks of it, it looks like it was parameterized from a circle equation. $r_e$ is the distance of the earth from the sun and, $r_m$ is the distance from the earth and the moon.

$$\mathbf{r}(t)=\begin{cases}r_e\cos{2\pi t/T_e+r_m\cos{2\pi t}/T_m}\\ r_e\sin{2\pi t/T_e}+r_m\sin2\pi t /T_m\end{cases}$$

Comment: Surely $T$ should have subscripts as well... In the one case being the time it takes the moon to orbit the earth and in the other case the time it takes the earth to orbit the sun.

Comment: you're right, my bad. Fixed the post now.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is a huge simplification of the problem of properly parametrizing this... but the short explanation is that if we were to use the sun's position as the origin and all other positions are considered relative to the sun's, assume that orbits are perfectly circular, and so on... that the first term in each coordinate is in reference to the offset of the moon in relation to the sun caused by the position of the earth, and the second term is the offset of the moon in relation to the earth...

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It is the result of the vector addition. Note that the vector distance of the earth from the sun and the vector distance of the moon from the earth are respectively,

$$\mathbf{r}_e(t)=\begin{cases}r_e\cos{2\pi t/T_e }\\ r_e\sin{2\pi t/T_e}\end{cases},\>\>\>\>\>
\mathbf{r}_m(t)=\begin{cases}r_m\cos{2\pi t/T_m }\\ r_m\sin{2\pi t/T_m}\end{cases}$$

The distance of the moon from the sun is just the vector summation of $\mathbf{r}_e$ and $\mathbf{r}_m$, i.e.

$$\mathbf{r}(t)=\mathbf{r}_e(t) + \mathbf{r}_m (t) = \begin{cases}r_e\cos{2\pi t/T_e+r_m\cos{2\pi t}/T_m}\\ r_e\sin{2\pi t/T_e}+r_m\sin2\pi t /T_m\end{cases}$$